# Is it necessary to use CDATA in RSS feed format?

Tags: rss, seo, web-deployment

In RSS feed, is CDATA really necessary to write? Can't we just give the main details and update the same every time? If so what are the advantages and dis-advantages? Any one out there to brief about the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does <!\[CDATA\[\]\]> in XML mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSS feed is valid XML document. So you have to use CDATA to mark content as textual data, not as markup.

Also: [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)